# some keys of my Lenovo U310 ideapad is not working

Tags: windows-8

I have a Lenovo U310 ideapad. I have troubles with the q,w,e,r,u,i,o and p keys, they are not working. But any other else my laptop is working fine. How can I make it work again? Does it need a cleaning or a keyboard replacement? If so, how can I replace the keyboard for it. As for now I am using a wireless keyboard.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the device under warranty?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any liquid spill on it or dust blow on it?

If yes, cleaning under the keys is necessary. Compressed air may be all it takes.

If that doesn't work and if you're out of warranty and don't mind the risk, you can gently try to lift one of the keys (if it will come off easily) and look for culprits there. Again you're warned this is risky and you could damage the device. Do this at your own risk. On some devices, the key caps are held by mini suction cups, so the key caps can be put back in place (but again I'm not familiar with your keyboard/device and this may not work or could damage.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's no non water liquid down there, try cleaning with alcohol then let it dry.

If there is no liquid incident you should try compressed air blow.

Third option is to open it and check bus voltages when pressing keys so you can find if its a hardware error or failure. If your laptops comes with a guarantee don't screw on it. Send it to professional people ;) Guarantee voids if they find screw traces